# Error installing modules for node.js

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, stylus

I installed node and everything was ok, but when I've tried to install stylus, for example didn't allow me to do it with :`nmp install -g stylus`, only with `:npm install stylus`.

When I try to compile estilos.styl anywhere, then the console gives me

> "command not found"

I tried to install stylus in the local folder too, but still same error. Same happens with grunt-cli or any module I try to install with node.

These are the errors:

```
iMac-de-Eva:~ eva$ npm install stylus -g npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus' npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus'] npm ERR!   errno: 3, npm ERR!  
code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory', npm ERR!   fstream_path:
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus', npm ERR!   fstream_class:
'DirWriter', npm ERR!   fstream_stack:  npm ERR!    [
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!     
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] } npm ERR!  npm
ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0 npm ERR! command "node"
"/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "stylus" "-g" npm ERR! cwd /Users/eva
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33 npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28 npm ERR! path
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus npm ERR! fstream_path
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus npm ERR! fstream_type Directory npm
ERR! fstream_class DirWriter npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! errno 3 npm
ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus'
npm ERR! fstream_stack
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53 npm
ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15) npm ERR!  npm ERR!
Additional logging details can be found in: npm ERR!    
/Users/eva/npm-debug.log npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [EACCESS Error when doing npm install -g bower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473281/eaccess-error-when-doing-npm-install-g-bower)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to install globally (which is what the `-g` switch means) you may have to use `sudo`: `sudo npm install -g [module-name]`

Answer (score 1):

*EACASSS error* means you do not have permissions.

To install globally you need to have elevated permissions, this will help:

```
sudo npm install -g stylus
```

It will ask you for the password for security reasons.

Installing locally works without permissions, but as you noticed, command `stylus` is not found, because it is installed locally and not included into your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install using this:

```
npm install --save [module-name]
```