# Can't install socket.io on windows 7 64 bits

Tags: windows, node.js

I've been trying to download socket.io for nodejs but every time I do I keep getting this error.

I am running it as an administrator but for some reason my system does not recognize that I am running this as one. Does anyone know why this is happening?

It keeps spitting back out code like this:

> npm ERR! node v0.12.2 npm ERR! npm v2.7.4 npm ERR! code EACCES npm
>   ERR! errno EACCES npm ERR! syscall connec
>
> npm ERR! Error: connect EACCES npm ERR!  at
>   exports._ernoException
>
> npm ERR!  { [Error: connect EACCES] code: 'EACCES', eerno, 'EACCES',
>   syscall: connect'}
>
> npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/administrator
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>       C:\Windows\System32\npm-debug.log

Comment: Did you elevate your command prompt?

Comment: Both EACCES and "Please try running this command again as root/administrator" indicate that the next thing to try is running the same command from a command prompt with admin privileges.  It would help if you also explained exactly what command you're typing from exactly which directory and whether you have any environment variables set that influence npm or node?

Comment: @jfriend00: No; this looks like it's coming from a network operation.

Comment: @SLaks - maybe, but the very error suggests trying as administrator so that sure seems like something to try.  And, many cases of EACCES in npm can be insufficient privileges too.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473281/eaccess-error-when-doing-npm-install-g-bower

Comment: The command I was using was npm install socket.io. And I tried downloading using the administrator cmd window but it still came up with the same error. Is there anyway to override that?